# connect to Arduino instead of Kobuki

Tags: arduino, serial, usb, turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be an easy question.

I want to run the kobuki software with a connection to Arduino instead of the Kobuki-base. To me it seems that it can be easily done by changing the Arduino serial port

> /dev/ttyACM0

to the Kobuki serial port

> /dev/kobuki

After trying everything I could think of, I still have no succes. I can create the /dev/kobuki port when the Arduino is connected - but it isn't connected so that reading and writing from that port gives the same results as reading and writing from the Arduino port. Am I overlooking a solution here?

Another easy option would be changing the software to connect to /dev/ttyACM0 instead of /dev/kobuki. However, I have no clue where in the code that part is happening, is there a specific file which handles this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270368/connect-to-arduino-instead-of-kobuki/) by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that changing the port in

> kobuki/src/kobuki/kobuki_node/param/base.yaml

to /dev/ttyACM0 is sufficient in this case.

---

Originally posted by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) with karma: 48 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0